# ¿Como funcionan exactamente los forms de Django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo una pagina web con Django.

Soy nuevo en esto y en el curso que tome para aprender, en la app de `users` tenia un modelo y un form, en el modelo los campos son:

**`user`, `phone_number`, `picture`, `created` y `modified`**

Mientras que en el form son:

**`username`, `password`, `password_confirmation`, `firs_name`, `last_name` y `email`**

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por que no se ponen todos estos datos en el archivos models? ¿Que función cumple exactamente el archivo form?
Saludos!

Comment: A que te refieres con poner "todos estos datos" en el archivo `models.py`?

Comment: Hola Julio, me refiero a porque no se ponen los datos del form en models. Y mi otra pregunta es, los datos que se ingresan a traves del form, se guardan en la base de datos tambien?

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ¿Los datos que se ingresan a traves del form, se guardan en la base de datos también?

Los forms en Django, se encargan de manejar, validar y ***"limpiar"*** los datos del formulario, los datos POST específicamente, en mi opinión esa es la función principal, tiene otras funciones, como generar código HTML automáticamente, etc.

Es algo complejo, pero detrás escena, los datos POST recibidos (`MyForm(request.POST)`), los valida, y los ***"limpia"*** es decir, **normaliza los datos como un objeto Python**.

Después de hacer bastantes validaciones sobre campos, los datos, etc, posteriormente **inicialisa** los atributos en el objeto o en la instancia, con los datos ya validados y limpios, algo así:

```
setattr(self.instance, field_name, field_data)
```

Ya que he leído un poco del código fuente, se como mas o menos como funciona, entonces para que entiendas mejor como es que funciona, he programado un `ModelForm` super sencillo, para que entiendas:

```
class CustomModelForm:

    def __init__(self, post_data, instance = None):

        if self.Meta.model is None and self.Meta.fields is None:
            raise Exception('...')

        self.instance = self.Meta.model() if instance is None else instance

        for field_name, field_value in zip(self.Meta.fields, post_data.values()):
            setattr(self.instance, field_name, field_value) # Inicialisamos los attr

    def save(self, commit = False): 
        return self.instance.save(commit = commit)
    
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = None
```

---

Ahora utilicemos ese `CustomModelForm`:

```
class MyForm(CustomModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

Funcionaria igual a un `ModelForm`, con las diferencias de que no tiene casi nada de validaciones, por ejemplo no valida que el atributo `fields`, de la clase `Meta` sea una tupla o lista y a su ves, verifique que esos atributos existan en el modelo, y así sucesivamente...

```
>>> form = MyForm(request.POST)
>>> form.save()
<MyModel: ...>
```

---

> Ahora que ya sabes como funciona, **¿Los datos que se ingresan a traves del form, se guardan en la base de datos también?**

Pues los datos como tal, no, el objeto si, es decir **se crea un registro en la db, con dichos datos**.

---

#### ¿Porque no se ponen los datos del form en models?

Respecto a esta duda, no la entiendo muy bien, pero creo que te confundes respecto al atributo `fields`, de la clase `Meta`.

El atributo `fields` en los forms, es para especificar que campos, se validaran, se inicialisaran en la instancia y se mostraran código HTML generado automáticamente.

No estoy seguro a que exactamente te refieres, si pudieras aclararlo seria lo ideal. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

***Soy nuevo en django, quizás no te daré la mejor explicación(muchos programadores expertos te darán una explicación técnica y si puedes seria mejor que las entendieras, yo te daré la resumida en criollo).***
En el archivo model.py es donde asignaras tus tablas que contendrá tu base de datos,  o sea, tus fotos, archivos, información, como el usuario se relacionara con la misma,etc.
Mientras que la función de los Formularios son para autenticar al usuario para poder manipular los mismos en el admin o pagina, por ejemplo, en un blog, un usuario podrá cargar una foto, información, etc. lo que hayas puesto en tu base de datos(models.py). En el admin veras la opción de Users(usuarios) y allí veras todos los usuarios que has creado y sus permisos administrativo, ellos podrán borrar, modificar, etc en tu modelo(base de datos) si tienen los permisos requeridos.

Tu pregunta es para que sirven los formularios, bueno son como una ficha de una persona, en el formulario puedes pedirle nombre completo, sexo, email, teléfono, etc. y esa ficha sirve para poder relacionarse con la base de datos.